# How to store pointer / iterator reference to stl container element in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, stl

I am designing a graph class which I want to base on an adjacency list. The class internally has a DataStructure :

```
std::unordered_map<Node,std::list<??>,NodeHash,NodeEqual> map;
```

Instead of `??`, I want either pointer to Node element stored in list or some iterator pointing to it.

I am new to C++. How should I go about it?

Comment: Use `Node*` at the `??`

Comment: How do I get pointer to an existing key node from the unordered_map?

Comment: use `&something` to get a `SomeClass*` type pointer.

Comment: Aside: is `map` supposed to be the *owner* of your `Node` objects, or supposed to contain *copies* of your `Node` objects? Or is ownership elsewhere and your *keys* should be pointers too?

Comment: I think the OP wants to do something recursive; i.e. an analogous thing for sequences would be `typedef std::vector<myvec::iterator> myvec;` (which doesn't work).

Comment: @Hurkyl The map is supposed to be the owner of nodes. I am simply implementing a custom graph class.

Comment: Incidentally, have you considered making the adjacency list a *member* of your `Node` class? (or alternatively, making a `GraphNode` class which contains a `Node` and a list of adjacent `GraphNode*`s?)

Comment: I haven't but is it a better way to solve the problem? if so why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get pointer to an existing key node from the unordered_map?

Find the element with that key, take the address of the `first` member of the element.

```
std::unordered_map<Node,std::list<Node*>,NodeHash,NodeEqual> map;
Node node1;
(void) map[node1];  // add { node1, {} }  to the map
...
auto iter = map.find(node1);
if (iter != map.end())
{
  Node* n = &iter->first;
  Node node2;
  map[node2].push_back(n);
}
```

Here `n` is a pointer to the existing key that is equal to `node1`.

Comment: I need const GNode *n = &iter->first; to make pointers work but then map[somenode].push_front(n); does not work :(

Comment: Ah, good point, map keys are `const` to prevent you from changing them and invalidating their location in the map. Can you use `std::list<const Node*>` instead? If not, you can use `const_cast<Node*>(&iter->first)` to get a non-const pointer, but you **must** make sure you don't alter the node's hash code through that pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This works in with `ideone`; I don't know if it's portable.

```
struct M;
typedef std::unordered_map<Node, std::list<M>, NodeHash, NodeEqual> mymap;
struct M { mymap::iterator x; };
```

Unfortunately, `M` isn't *quite* an iterator to `mymap`, but it's pretty close.

(`ideone` complains if I try the same trick to make `M` a wrapper of `std::list<mymap::iterator>` instead)

Comment: It's technically undefined behaviour, because `mymap::iterator` instantiates `std::list<M>` which is an incomplete type at that poiint, which is forbidden by [res.on.functions].  It should work with all implementations though, because in practice `std::list<M>` doesn't actually require a complete type until you try to do something with it.